# Pig how to format a semi-structured CSV with filters

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig

I have semi-structured CSV , which looks something like this.

```css
VTS,01,0099,7022606164,SP,GP,33,060646,A,1258.9805,N,07735.9303,E,0.0,278.6,280515,0000,00,4000,11,999,842,4B61
VTS,01,0099,7022606164,NM,GP,20,060637,A,1258.9805,N,07735.9302,E,0.0,278.6,280515,0000,00,4000,11,999,841,7407+++
VTS,66,0065,7022606164,NM,0,GP,22,060648,280515,1258.9804,N,07735.9301,E,04AE+++
VTS,01,0099,7022606164,NM,GP,22,060656,A,1258.9804,N,07735.9301,E,0.0,278.6,280515,0000,00,4000,11,999,843,8FEB+++
VTS,01,0099,7022606164,NM,GP,22,060721,A,1258.9803,N,07735.9304,E,0.0,278.6,280515,0000,00,4000,11,999,845,044D++++++
VTS,99,0065,7022606164,NM,0,A,GP,22,060648,280515,1258.9804,N,07735.9301,E,04AE+++
VTS,99,0065,7022606164,NM,0,A,GP,22,060648,280515,1258.9804,N,07735.9301,E,04AE
```

I want to make make three different tables with this data. i.e. one with VTS,01 another with VTS,99 and another with VTS,66. Again I also need to remove the "+++" attached with each line as its an error, for which I have written this pig script.

```css
data = load '/user/simulator/SKYTRACK/27thMay2015' using PigStorage('\n') as (f1:chararray);
splt = foreach data generate FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0, '\\+++'));
data_pkt = FILTER splt BY $0 MATCHES '.*VTS,01+.*';
sos_pkt = FILTER splt BY $1 MATCHES '.*VTS,99+.*';
health_pkt = FILTER splt BY $2 MATCHES '.*VTS,66+.*';
```

When I am testing this scripts individually for each of the table only one output I receive the rest with no output,

`dump data_pkt;
dump sos_pkt;
dump health_pkt;`

I am very much new to pig so can anyone help me to solve this issue..It will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the +++, you also need to escape all the "+" and not just the only one.
You were not very specific on the meaning of these pluses. You could rather use that regex to split :

```
 "\\+{3,}"
```

And consequently, in your pig script :

```
splt = foreach data generate FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0, '\\+{3,}'));
```

Altough Aman is correct, however, I would rather use SPLIT instead of FILTER to separate the datasets :

```
 a = load '/abc.txt';
 SPLIT a INTO 
     b01 IF $1 == 01,
     b66 IF $1 == 66,
     b99 IF $1 == 69;
```

Comment: You forgot to add `using PigStorage(',')`, as by default it will look for tabs so your answer won't work.

Comment: now it worked fine for me`a = load '/abc.txt' using PigStorage(',');
SPLIT a INTO b01 IF $1 == 01, b66 IF $1 == 66, b99 IF $1 == 69;` Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

This will filter your record depending upon the value.

```
 a = load '/abc.txt' using PigStorage(',');
 b1 = FILTER a by $1==01;
 b66 = FILTER a by $1==66;
 b99 = FILTER a by $1==99;
```

And for removing +++ You have to write a simple pig udf.

Out put:

```
(VTS,99,0065,7022606164,NM,0,A,GP,22,060648,280515,1258.9804,N,07735.9301,E,04AE+++)
(VTS,99,0065,7022606164,NM,0,A,GP,22,060648,280515,1258.9804,N,07735.9301,E,04AE)
```

Comment: You forgot to add `using PigStorage(',')`, as by default it will look for tabs so your answer won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is working some what decent now.

```css
data = load '/user/simulator/SKYTRACK/27thMay2015' using PigStorage(',');

splt = foreach data generate $0 as col0:chararray,$1 as col1:chararray,$2 as col2:chararray,$3 as col3:chararray,$4 as col4:chararray,$5 as col5:chararray,$6 as col6:chararray,$7 as col7:chararray,$8 as col8:chararray,$9 as col9:chararray,$10 as col10:chararray,$11 as col11:chararray,$12 as col12:chararray,$13, FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($14, '\\+++'));

data_pkt = FILTER splt BY $1 MATCHES '.*01+.*';
health_pkt = FILTER splt BY $1 MATCHES '.*66+.*';
sos_pkt = FILTER splt BY $1 MATCHES '.*99+.*';
```

but the problem is three step.

Comment: To split the data depending on the value of column one, take a look at @g.l answer, to avoid 3 `filter` operations.